# NoReverseMatch for Django and DjangoCMS App

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to set up some URLs for tags and categories on a forum. The links look like this

```
<a href="{% url 'article-list-by-tag' %}{{ tag }}" class="badge badge-info" >{{ tag }}</a>
```

The URL pattern `article-list-by-tag` comes from a DjangoCMS app called AldrynNewsblog. It can be found [HERE](https://github.com/divio/aldryn-newsblog/blob/master/aldryn_newsblog/urls.py) and looks like this

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w[-\w]*)/',
    TagArticleList.as_view(), name='article-list-by-tag'),
```

Note that the NewsBlog does not have `app_name` declared in its `urls.py`.

The app itself is part of a larger Django app called DjangoCMS. The url entry-point for the latter is declared in project's main `urls.py` as follows:

```
path('', include('cms.urls')),
```

The error that I am getting is

```
Reverse for 'article-list-by-tag' not found. 'article-list-by-tag' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

What should I do to resolve this? I have tried adding namespace to various URL entries as well as `app_name` to NewsBlog to no avail. The Django version being used is 2.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `.slug` of the `tag` as parameter of the URL, so:

```
<a href="{% url 'article-list-by-tag' tag=tag.slug %}" class="badge badge-info" >{{ tag }}</a>
```

If you import it with a namespace, you need to prefix the name of the view with that prefix, so `'some_namespace:article-list-by-tag'`.

Comment: I have tried it, and it does not solve the issue. The issue is that the pattern is not recognized. I do not see how adding the slug would help that. Am I missing something?

P.S. You are probably right about the slug (I'll find out once the pattern is recognized).

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, the following code worked for my use-case:

`<a href="{% namespace_url 'article-list-by-tag' tag=tag.slug %}" class="badge badge-info" >{{ tag }}</a>`

Where the `namespace_url` is a template tag provided by DjangoCMS.